# How to create a list of images and their names in a folder

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I am using the following code to create a list of image files with tif extension. The current result of the code is a list with the address of the .tif files.

```
raster_list=[]

def getFiles(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
            raster_list.append(os.path.join(path, file))
getFiles(fpath)
print(raster_list)
len(raster_list)
```

result:

```
['C:/dataset/test\\ras1.tif', 'C:dataset/test\\ras2.tif', 'C:/dataset/test\\ras3.tif', 'C:/dataset/test\\ras4.tif', 'C:/dataset/test\\ras5.tif']
```

How can I revise the code to create two lists a) name of the file with .tif b) name of the file. here is the example:

```
raster_list = ['ras1.tif','ras2.tif','ras3.tif','ras4.tif', 'ras5.tif' ]
raster_name = ['ras1','ras2','ras3','ras4', 'ras5']
```

---

edit to the code from solutions:

```
from os import path
raster_list=[]

def getFiles(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
            raster_list.append(file) #remove the os.join, just take the file name
getFiles(fpath)
raster_names = [path.splitext(x)[0] for x in raster_list]
print(raster_list)
print(raster_names)
```

result:

```
['ras1.tif', 'ras2.tif', 'ras3.tif', 'ras4.tif', 'ras5.tif']
['ras1', 'ras2', 'ras3', 'ras4', 'ras5']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first list you want you can just use the function split("") on each one of the term of your list and use the last element of the list created by split.
And for the second one you can just take the first list you've created and split on ".", you will just have to save the first element of the list.

```
L = ['C:/dataset/test\\ras1.tif', 'C:dataset/test\\ras2.tif', 'C:/dataset/test\\ras3.tif', 'C:/dataset/test\\ras4.tif', 'C:/dataset/test\\ras5.tif']
raster_list = []
raster_name = []
for i in L:
    a = i.split("\\")[1]
    raster_list.append(a)
    raster_name.append(a.split(".")[0])
print(raster_list, raster_name)
```

But you can also try to not include the path in rather_list like that:

```
raster_list=[]

def getFiles(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
            raster_list.append(file) #remove the os.join, just take the file name
getFiles(fpath)
print(raster_list)
len(raster_list)
```

You can merge the two to have this:

```
raster_list=[]
raster_names=[]

def getFiles(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".tif"):
            raster_list.append(file) 
            raster_names.append(file.split(".")[0])

getFiles(fpath)
print(raster_list, raster_names)
```

Comment: @ hinzelin The second code helps to display raster_list. Is it possible to change the first code and remove L for displaying the raster_names as well?

Comment: I merged the two codes to create what you may want, as that you can see the process to find the solution by yourself the next time. (I edited my answer so the code is above). I can't test this solution so you will have to test it to be sure it works :)

Comment: @ hinzelin, Thanks for your time. your code returns empty list for  raster_name. I edited your code in the question. Is it a good idea to put raster_names out of def?

Comment: Ho nevermind I'm stupid I just writed raster_name instead of raster_names, I've edited to correct that, it may work now.
If you put raster_names out of def it becomes a global variable https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_variables_global.asp
It can be good depending on your project, but I'm not really qualified for explaining that

Comment: Thanks for your update to code and info about global variable. Your code works fine.

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I would use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) because it's OS independent and reliable:

```py
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> files = ['/tmp/ras1.tif', '/tmp/ras2.tif', '/tmp/ras3.tif']
>>> [Path(file).name for file in files]
['ras1.tif', 'ras2.tif', 'ras3.tif']
>>> [Path(file).stem for file in files]
['ras1', 'ras2', 'ras3']
```

Comment: @ gribvirus74, Is there any way to avoid defining files variable? I wonder if I have many .tif images how I should add all the addresses in files.

Comment: @Sam sure, you can get creative with map and the `operator` module

Comment: @Sam yeah, of course it's possible, it's only for demonstration purposes

Answer (score 0):

split by '\', take the last element and append it to first list,
then split that by '.', take first element and append it to second list?

Alternatively, you can use these in-built functions: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the os.path() methods to achieve what you want.

```
import os
raster_list = []
raster_name = []

def getFiles(path):
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        if file.endswith(".tif"): 
            raster_list.append(os.path.basename(file))
            raster_name.append(os.path.splitext(file)[0])

getFiles(fpath)
print(raster_list)
print(raster_name)

len(raster_list)
```

Comment: you already have the file name on `file`, no need to do extra work by getting it from `filepath`

Comment: @ stanulilic when I print raster_list and raster_names, it results in empty lists.